# Emacs Python interpreter tweaks

Tags: emacs, mode, key-bindings

Having minor issue configuring emacs. I am trying to re-assign the M-Tab key binding for anything code completion as its already bound to ubuntu unity "tab/page viewer".

```
(require 'anything)
(require 'anything-ipython)
(when (require 'anything-show-completion nil t)
  (use-anything-show-completion 'anything-ipython-complete
                            '(length initial-pattern)))
```

These are the attempts I have had to rebind it. don't particularly want  but I know its not taken by anything else.

```
;;; (define-key anything-mode-map (kbd "<F9>") 'anything)
;;; (define-key anything-show-completion-mode-map (kbd "<F9>") 'anything)
;;; (define-key anything-show-completion-map (kbd "<F9>") 'anything)
```

Just can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that you want to use lower-case "f9": `(kbd "<f9>")` instead of `(kbd "<F9>")`.

You can check with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> to see what Emacs reports that key as being, and use that same string verbatim as the argument to`(kbd)`.

Also note that you use <kbd>ESC</kbd> as a substitute for <kbd>Meta</kbd> -- Emacs will translate it. So <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> will do the same as <kbd>M-TAB</kbd>. And in the case of TAB, you can also generate that character code with <kbd>C-i</kbd>, so <kbd>M-C-i</kbd> is another existing binding.

I looked up the files you mentioned, and anything-ipython.el seems to be the only one which binds <kbd>M-TAB</kbd>, and based on its installation instructions you should already have the following code:

```
;;  Install: 
;;  =======
;;
;; Setup anything python:
;; Put this file in your load path.
;; Add to .emacs:
;;
;; (require 'anything-ipython)
;; (add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
;;                                 (define-key py-mode-map (kbd "M-<tab>") 'anything-ipython-complete)))
;; (add-hook 'ipython-shell-hook #'(lambda ()
;;                                   (define-key py-mode-map (kbd "M-<tab>") 'anything-ipython-complete)))
;;
```

So I'm guessing that's what you want to be changing.

Comment: updated my attempts using the <f9> format. The issue is none of my attempts work and I cannot test M-Tab with C-h k as it always takes me to the ubuntu unity page/viewer.

Comment: @sayth I have changed the keyboard short for "moving between the windows" win-tab (windows key with tab) in my ubuntu. Sothat I can use M-tab in emacs

Comment: sayth: Ah, so you don't actually know what command you need to bind it to? I've added some more info to my reply.

Comment: The answer is correct for getting the keyboard working. Something unknown causing 'anything' to be void.                                                                            Symbols function defintion is void: anything

Comment: I've attempted to use the code above for exactly the same issue, but when I check the binding with C-h k, I get "undefined" - I don't suppose you had any luck with this did you?